# HTTP4 Component configuration for HTTPS tunneling through HTTP proxy results in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'http4' not registered

Tags: https, proxy, apache-camel

I'm trying to tunnel HTTPS connections through an HTTP proxy, using Camel's HTTP4 component.

I have several routes so I would like to configure the proxy at the component level rather than the route definition level.

I set the following in the camel context:

```
http.proxyHost=myproxy.mydomain.com
http.proxyPort=80
http.proxyScheme=http4
```

An example of one my routes:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("https4://www.verisign.com")
    .to("direct:downloadProcessor");
```

When I execute this route it produces an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'http4' not registered.`

However, if I specify the proxy configuration on each of my route definitions:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("https4://www.verisign.com?proxyAuthHost=myproxy.mydomain.com&proxyAuthPort=80&proxyAuthScheme=http4")
    .to("direct:downloadProcessor");
```

it works fine and I can see the CONNECT request in the log `DEBUG DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: CONNECT www.verisign.com:443 HTTP/1.1`:

It sounds a bit like the problems found during testing of [CAMEL-4176](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4176?focusedCommentId=13065644&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13065644) but this is marked as fixed in Camel 2.8.0 (I'm using 2.10.0).

Is there some reason I can't configure the proxy on the HTTP component instead of each route?

Comment: Discussed and answered at the Camel mailing list
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Using-the-HTTP4-component-to-make-a-HTTPS-call-behind-proxy-sever-tp5719105.html Can you mark this as answered/closed?

Comment: Short answer is to use the above workaround and a JIRA has been raised: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5595

Comment: Just encountered this exact problem with migration of some old legacy code!